# Generating a char using input from user in C++

Tags: c++, string, loops, char

I wish to make a char with digits between 0-9. The user decides how many digits to use. 
For example, if the user inputs 4, the char should be 01234.
Please note I cannot use the string data type. I have to use char. 
I know how to generate a string for the same logic but not a char.
So if there is a way to convert string to char, that will work well. I tried

```
string randomString; //this contains the set of numbers 0-9 on the basis of the users  input 
char charString = randomString;
```

This however does not work.

Comment: Not knowing much about C++ I'm assuming the type `char` can just hold a 1-byte integer (only a character, letter or number). Here you can read more: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/27-chars/

Comment: Terrible question; lazy and did not want  to look up. The function is well documented.

Answer (score 2):

> So if there is a way to convert string to char

Yes, it's called a character array and you can easily convert a string type to a character array like so:

```
const char* charString = randomString.c_str();
```

You can find more information about `c_str()` method [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) and you should review [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ntcs/) material regarding character arrays.

If you require a non-const (can be modified) character array, refer to the above links which will explain it and actually give examples about how to accomplish that.

Comment: Should not be a const, char* is fine. In fact, we do not know how he will use it.

Comment: Perhaps. Not knowing how he will use it is the least of his concerns. There's an apparent lack of understanding it would seem.

Comment: I am just being too picky; I apologize.

Comment: @JavaManTeaMan Not at all. No apology needed.